# Cannot recover Database from ibdata file

Tags: mysql, restore, ibdata

My Server recently had a Kernel-Panic and I downloaded all the mysql data using the rescue mode.

Now when I upload the ibdata1 file and table folders to a local XAMPP Server and click on a table to view it's data(phpmyadmin), it says

```
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__table_uiprefs' doesn't exist in engine
```

My old Server had Plesk installed, maybe Plesk-MySQL has a different ibdata1 structure, compared to MySQL from XAMPP.

I hope anyone can help me to get my data back.

Comment: Did you also recover the `.frm` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to MySQL other than thru PHPMyAdmin, you could try recreating the table. Practice this at your own risk thou.

[create_tables.sql](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql)

Answer (score 0):

You're in Disaster Recovery Territory here so there really ought to be only *one* train of thought in your mind.

- Reach for your **Recovery Strategy**.
- Extract from it your Recovery Plan, which you've practised and rehearsed many times before,
- Get the database back from the Backups that you've been taking.